# excel vba copy-paste a shape and saveas 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

I'm experiencing a 1004 runtime error when saving a workbook (wbk_New) on which I copy-pasted a group of shapes from another workbook (wbk_Old). I should tell that a macro from wbk_Old is assigned to this group.

```
wbk_Old.Worksheets("DashBoard").Activate
ChartTop = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").Top
ChartLeft = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").Left
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").OnAction = ""
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").Copy

wbk_New.Worksheets("DashBoard").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").Delete
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").Top = ChartTop
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").Left = ChartLeft
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group_VesselGraphics").OnAction = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!UpdateShipGraph"

wbk_Old.Close
wbk_New.SaveAs As path_Old
```

I can't figure out what is causing this error...Does anyone have already faced this issue ?

Thanks a ton for your help !

(I forgot to mention that a chart also belong to this group of shapes!)

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the exact error message?

Comment: And if I want to save it manually I have an excel "Repairs" popup window saying: "Damage to the file was so extensive that repairs were not possible. Excel attempted to save your formulas and values, but some data may have been lost or corrupted."

Comment: Seems like your excel file is corrupt. Is it possible to create a new file from scratch and testing the code?

Comment: The error msg is just saying "Run-time error '1004': Cannot access 'filename'" 
(sorry for the snapshot I'm a newbie and can't post image) 
I understand that my file is corrupted but I don't understand why ! Do you think it could be linked to the macro associated to the group shape ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't understand why but it seems that some links were still existing between "wbk_New" and "wbk_Old" although I broke all the links and updated the chart to refer to intrinsic data.
Hence, closing of "wbk_Old" couldn't be properly performed and wbk_New became corrupted, so that it was impossible to save it.

The only way I found to work around this issue is to save (on itself) wbk_New before closing wbk_Old and then to call an external process that replace wbk_Old by wbk_New, using a delay of 4s, and to close wbk_New and Old before the delay completed.
I have to admit that this is an ugly solution, if someone knows a better way it would be nice to share it!

Here below is the code of my solution, where BatchCmd creates a batch file of a command and shell it:

```
{code above}
wbk_New.Save
cmd = "ping -n 4 127.0.0.1 >nul" + vbCrLf
cmd = cmd + "move /Y " & path_New & " " & path_Old
Call BatchCmd(cmd, status:=vbHide)
wbk_Old.Close
wbk_New.Close
```